# Prove the following statement: if $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n = L $ and $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n = M$, then $L=M$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

I was going through some practice problems for an upcoming calculus exam and I came across the question: "Prove the following statement: if $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n = L $ and $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n = M$, then $L=M$". Here is what I tried to do:$$$$
Assume $L\neq M$. Therefore, $L=M+k$ where $k$ is some real value. So we can rewrite $$\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n - \lim _{n\to \infty }a_n = L-M = M+k-M =k$$ $$\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n - \lim _{n\to \infty }a_n =\lim _{n\to \infty }(a_n-a_n) = \lim _{n\to \infty }0 = 0 $$ $$\therefore k=0 $$ From there we can conclude from subbing $k=0$ that $L=M+0=M $ and this contradicts the statement $L\neq M$ so by contradiction $L=M$ must be true. $$$$
Is there anything wrong with this proof? I know for proving the uniqueness of limits theorem you have to do more but that isn't exactly what the question is asking.

Comment: No, this isn't what they're asking for. They're asking you to treat the expression $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = M$ purely as shorthand for the $\epsilon-N$ definition of a limit and not as an equality. If you do this, it doesn't make sense to form the expression $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n - \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$ since you haven't shown uniqueness of limits.

Comment: I think it's a poorly worded question.  If you have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = M$, as you've copied the question, then it's a much simpler proof to write $$L = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = M.$$  I expect @MarkSaving is correct about their intentions, though, so you probably are expected to show that the limit is unique.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Agreed.

Comment: You can't write $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n - \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ before you've demonstrated that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ has a well-defined value. Indeed, what does the subtraction even mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is subtly circular, but there is something that can be salvaged from it. As it turns out, yes, you can actually apply algebra of limits to show that $0 = a_n - a_n \to L - M = k$. The proof of the algebra of limits theorem doesn't rely on uniqueness at all; that is if $a$ is one of the possibly many limits of $a_n$, and $b$ is one of the possibly many limits of $b_n$, then $a - b$ is one of the possibly many limits of $a_n - b_n$.

But, in your last conclusion, you say because $0$ is a limit of $0$ and $k$ is a limit of $0$, then $0 = k$. This **assumes** what you want to prove, but instead of assuming it for the arbitrary convergent sequence $a_n$, you are now assuming it about the very nice constant sequence $0$. While the proof is circular so far, it is what I would consider progress!

We just now need to show that the only limit of the $0$ sequence is $0$. I will let you think about how to do this. Why does the constant $0$ sequence not get any $\varepsilon$-close to any other $k \neq 0$? It would have to, say, get $|k|/2$-close. Why is this impossible?

Answer (score 3):

I have thought immediately to the limit uniqueness theorem for sequences that asserts:

> A $\{a_n\}$ sequence of real numbers cannot have two distinct limit $L$ and $M$. In fact if we suppose that $L\ne M$ are (finite; in truth, one can easily remove this restriction) limits of the $\{a_n\}$, we will show that $L=M$.

By the definition of a limit, for every $\varepsilon> 0$ (real number) exist $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ such that for every $n>\nu_1$ it is true $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon/2$, and for every $n> \nu_2$ it is true $|a_n-M|<\varepsilon/2 $ . Let $N=\max\{\nu_1, \nu_2\}$ then for every $n > N$
$$|L-M|\leq|L-a_n|+|a_n-M| <\varepsilon$$
for the  triangular inequality.  So $|L-M| <\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon >0$, and so $|L-M|=0$. Hence $$L=M, \qquad \blacksquare$$

Answer (score 2):

As noticed your proof is not correct. Assuming by contradiction as you did $L\neq M$, we can proceed by the definition

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n = L \iff \forall\varepsilon \quad \exists n_L \quad \forall n>n_L \quad |a_n-L|<\varepsilon$$

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n = M \iff \forall\varepsilon \quad \exists n_M \quad \forall n>n_M \quad |a_n-M|<\varepsilon$$

and then fix $\varepsilon \le \frac{|M-L|}3$.

Can you conclude form here?

Comment: note to op: there is really no need for contradiction, as this suffices as a direct proof, since two real numbers $a,b$ are equal iff $\forall\varepsilon>0,|a-b|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @C Squared, although is necessary a proof by contradiction to prove that, if a non-negative number is smaller than any positive number, then the number is zero.

Comment: @CSquared In nay case I'm not claiming that we need a proof by contradiction, I've given a hint to proceed starting by a contradiction as the OP did.

Comment: @user i understand that, that's why i said note to the reader. your proof outline/hint works perfectly well as a direct proof.

Comment: @R.W.Prado counter-point: if $a\neq b$, then $|a-b|>|a-b|/2>0$ which proves the contrapositive. no contradiction necessary.

Comment: *note to the original poster (BlastKast)